# If else statement error in java no run time error

Tags: java, if-statement, logic, logical-operators

This is my code:

```
public class part {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] timea = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int[] timeb = {3,5};
        int k1 = 0, k2 = 0;
        while(k1 < timea.length && k2 < timeb.length) {
            if (timea[k1] < timeb[k2]) {
                System.out.println("Timeb is big");
                k1++;
            } else if (timea[k1] == timeb[k2]) {
                System.out.println("We are same");
                k2++;
            } else if (timea[k1] > timeb[k2]) {
                System.out.println("Timea is big");
                k1++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Timeb is big
Timeb is big
We are same
Timeb is big
we are same
```

My problem is that `Timea is big` never printed. But as per my logic

```
 else if (timea[k1] > timeb[k2]) {
     System.out.println("Timea is big");
     k1++;
 }
```

This code block is executed when it get {6} but I cannot understand why this portion not executed? Is there any logical error in my code block?

Comment: Just use your debuger, or add println in the code to display the value of each variable at each iteration, and you will understand

Comment: Hint Hint check what happens once you do `k2++`. What is the condition of your `while-loop` next iteration.

Comment: Can you share what you are trying to achieve by this code? As per your code k2 become 1. So while loop will not execute again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay let's do the trace:

```
k1=0, k2=0:

timea[0]=1, timeb[0]=3
Timeb is big

k1=1, k2=0:

timea[1]=2, timeb[0]=3
Timeb is big

k1=2, k2=0:

timea[2]=3, timeb[0]=3
We are same

k1=2, k2=1:

k2 is bigger than timeb length, therefore the while loop ends
```

That part of the code will never be executed under those example arrays...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a logical error.

When you get the value of `k2` bigger than `0`, the while loop is finishing, because of its condition `while(k1<timea.length && k2<timeb.length)`.
When you pass to the second if, the value of `k2` is incremented, to `1`, and this doesn't satisfy the while loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it never prints because it never gets to it.

```
 int [] timea={1,2,3,4,5,6};
 int [] timeb={3};
```

So your while loop: `while(k1<timea.length && k2<timeb.length)`

The size of `timea` is 6, the size of `timeb` is 1.

In the first iteration, it compares 1 to 3.
Since `timea[k1]` which is 1 is less than `timea[k2]` which is 3 it prints `"Timeb is big"` and increments `k1` by 1.

In the second iteration, it compares 2 to 3. Since `timea[k1]` which is 2 is less than `timea[k2]` which is 3 it prints `"Timeb is big"` and increments `k1` by 1.

Then in the third (and last) iteration it compares 3 to 3. Since `timea[k1]` which is 3 is equal to`timea[k2]` which is 3 it prints `"We are same"` and increments `k2` by 1.

But this time since `k2` is 1 and in your while loop your condition says in order to continue `k2` *MUST* be less than the size of `timeb` (which is also 1) it can't continue to the next iteration of the loop because there is only one element.

Does this make sense?